# Convert strings to date and time in Anylogic

Tags: string, anylogic, string-to-datetime

my agent has the next information as parameters:
year, month, day, hour, minute second. Now I want to transform all these parameters to a date by using
`toDate(year, month, hour, minute, second)`
But somehow I still get the error that I can only include three things to make a date (see picture below) But I also want to include the time how can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toDate(int, int, int, int, int, int)` (i.e. 6 arguments, not 4) as below:
[image]

PS: Learn to use code-complete (Ctrl+space on Windows) so you get these helpful popups yourself :)

Comment: Stupid mistakes, oops thanks for the answer.

Comment: no probs, happy to help